# Trying to insert some HTML inside jQuery datepicker div

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to dynamically insert some html inside jQuery ui datepicker containing div using append but just can't get it to work.

Here's what i've got so far:

```
$("#dt1").datepicker({
    beforeShow:function(textbox, instance){
        $("#ui-datepicker-div").append("<b>Appended text</b>");
    }
});
```

Trying to get it to work so it previews like this:

```
<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker">
    <b>Appended text</b>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need to wait till the datepicker content inserted into the box so you can use `setTimeout()` to do this work.

```js
$("#dt1").datepicker({
  beforeShow:function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $("#ui-datepicker-div").append("<b>Appended text</b>"); 
    }, 10);
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="dt1">
```

Comment: Perfect. Had a feeling it might be down to the datepicker triggering at the same time. So it makes perfect sense to set a timeout. Thanks